# Return nested ordered list with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following objects:

- Schedule

  - Days
  - Playlists
  - Media & Graphics

Schedule has many days, days has many playlists, playlists has both media and graphics.

I need to return a Schedule object with the Media and Graphics nested objects ordered by their start dates parameter.

To access a media list inside a schedule i use this:

```
device.schedule.days.SelectMany(d => d.playlists).SelectMany(p => p.media).OrderBy(m => m.start_time);
```

How can I properly just return the Schedule with the ordered media and the graphics? (Media and Graphics are both nested under Playlist object.

Thanks.

### EDIT

Solved it using the below (Highly appreciate sharing if there is a better approach to this):
   var schedule = device.schedule;

```
            foreach (var day in schedule.days)
            {
                foreach (var playlist in day.playlists)
                {
                    var media = playlist.media;
                    playlist.media = media.OrderBy(m => m.start_time).ToList();

                    var graphics = playlist.graphics;
                    playlist.graphics = graphics.OrderBy(g => g.start_time).ToList();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the code of Schedule?

If so, it might be helpful to have a common interface for both items (that has the property `start_time`) and then use that to order them inside the playlist.

I guess that would also require that `playlist` includes a list or an enumerable for both of these items, and you can select whether you want media or graphics with something like `.Where(x => x.GetType() == Media)`, or have that hidden behind some other property like you already use `media` here.